# Nine patch Images , when to use it?

Tags: android, android-image

Really, I so disappointed,May I know when to use image resource in nine patch format?

For example, 
I have default image resource for user profile photo for image view with (50 * 50)dp in phone sets. and i want to make the size of the image view in tablets (70 * 70)dp.
Upon which criteria i use nine path image over making another image resource for table with higher (width,height)?

Another question, 
In some examples i see them exporting nine patch images for all resolutions (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi) why they are making that?

Comment: disappointed? can you explain?

Comment: `when to use` ... Whenerver you need to stretch an image, in a controlled manner.

Comment: "i see them exporting nine patch images for all resolutions (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi) why they are making that?" -- because they want the non-stretched regions of their nine-patch PNG files to have better quality on higher density devices. Non-stretched regions, like the "corners" of rounded rectangles, may wind up being too small on high-density devices or too large on low-density devices.

Answer (score 1):

***What is 9 Patch PNG Images?***

9 patch scalable graphics are PNG based images that have 9 areas, called patches, that scale separately.

This is handy for mobile devices that have smaller screens with differing resolutions and aspect ratios. The Android SDK comes with a utility called draw9patch to create 9 patch images from PNG files. The draw9patch utility is located in the tools/ directory of the SDK.

The easiest way to think of a 9 patch image is to lay a tic-tac-toe board over the image. The grid from the tic-tac-toe board can then be moved across the image to fit the correct scaling zones. The 4 corner scaling zones don't scale. These are fixed size blocks. The top and bottom center column blocks only scale horizontally. The left and right edge boxes on row 2 only scale vertically. Finally the center scales both vertically and horizontally.

***When to use 9 Patch PNG ?***

A nine-patch-image is used in android to and normally ends width the extension *.9.png and is used to make a image stretchable without destroying the corners.

Comment: So can i use it to stretch any image Or just for images like background of buttons and edit texts ?

Comment: Not just for buttons, but also frames. The nine patch can specify non-contiguous areas to scale.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think you want to place button which has android:layout_width="match_parent" attribute in your activity. If you want to change background image which has round corner ([this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)), you should consider many different display size. Bigger display size stretches whole image and round corner may look ugly.
9 patch image can keep round corner size but stretch other parts (which is called "content area"). So it's better solution to provide same UI to multiple device users.